# Problema con Array to string conversion

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Estoy tratando de enviar un `array` en un formulario `Modal`, solo que me manda el error de `Array to string conversion`.
Tengo las librerias y los `scripts` correspondientes, pero a la hora de enviar mi formulario con un método `POST` me aparece el error y no se hace el registro en mi base de datos .

MODELO

```
class AreasUsuarios extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'tb_areasusuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_areasusuarios';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_area',
        'id_usuario',
        'activo',
        'id_registro'
    ];
}
```

CONTROLADOR

```
public function store(Request $request){

    //dd($request ->all());
    $areausuario = new AreasUsuarios();
    $areausuario -> id_area = $request -> id_area;
    $areausuario -> id_usuario = $request -> id_usuario;
    $areausuario -> activo = $request -> activo;
    $areausuario -> save();        
    return redirect()->route('areas-usuarios.index');
}
```

HMTL MODAL (la sección donde lleno los campos)

```
<div>
    <label for="floatingInput">Selecciona uno o varios usuarios:</label>
    <select data-search="true" data-silent-initial-value-set="true"  name="id_usuario[]" multiple>
    @foreach ($usuarios as $info)
         <option value="{{ $info->id_usuario }}">{{ $info->nombre }} {{$info->app}} {{$info->apm}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Si el tipo de dato de la culumna en bd es varchar o integer, no vas a poder guardar un array ahí. Explica lo que quieres hacer con esos multiples ids de usuario y como es la estructura de la tabla

Comment: También sería sería útil el mensaje de error completo, probablemente en los logs te indique hasta el archivo y la linea donde se lanza la excepción

Comment: Déjanos saber si alguna de las respuestas o comentarios solucionó tu problema marcándola con el check y con el upvote del lado izquierdo. En caso contrario, deja un comentario para tratar de darte otras soluciones.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en el controlador, cuando recibes esta línea:

```
$areausuario -> id_usuario = $request -> id_usuario;
```

Ya que en el formulario estás indicando que vas a enviar un `array` y que este puede ser de tipo `multiple`...

```
name="id_usuario[]" multiple
```

Pero en su lugar estás tratando este `array` como si fuese un `string`.

Una posible solución es que en el controlador iteres el **id_usuario** con un ciclo dentro de la función.

```
public function store(Request $request){
    //Te debe estar llegando un array en $request -> id_usuario
    //Puedes comprobarlo con la función print_r($request)
    $usuarios = $request -> id_usuario;
    //Iterar el array 
    foreach($usuarios as $usuario) {
        $areausuario = new AreasUsuarios();
        //dd($request ->all());
        $areausuario -> id_area = $request -> id_area;
        $areausuario -> id_usuario = $usuario;
        $areausuario -> activo = $request -> activo;
        $areausuario -> save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('areas-usuarios.index');
}
```